# How to register http client service in Blazer component

Tags: c#, visual-studio, api, asp.net-core

I am getting below error while i am trying to access the values from db in my blazor component,

Error:

- "Unhandled exception rendering component: Cannot provide a value for
  property 'EmployeService' on type
  'BlazorApp.Client.Pages.EmpData.EmployeeList'. There is no registered
  service of type 'BlazorApp.Client.Services.IEmployeeService'.

here is my code for component:
"
interface:

```html
  public interface IEmployeeService
{
    Task<IEnumerable<Employee>> GetEmployee();

}
```

Consuming the interface:

```html
public class EmployeeService : IEmployeeService
    {
        private readonly HttpClient httpClient;
        public EmployeeService(HttpClient httpClient)
        {
            this.httpClient = httpClient;
        }
        public async Task<IEnumerable<Employee>> GetEmployee()
        {
            return await httpClient.GetJsonAsync<Employee[]>("api/Employees");
        }
    }
```

And my Blazer component code:

```
public class EmployeeListBase:ComponentBase
    {
        [Inject]
        public IEmployeeService EmployeService { get; set;}
        public IEnumerable<Employee> Employees { get; set; }

        protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
        {
            Employees = (await EmployeService.GetEmployee()).ToList();
          
        }       
    }
```

Even I tried to register service in blazor component as there is not startup.cs exist, so I used program.cs to register, but even after using below code problem still persist:

```
builder.Services.AddScoped<IEmployeeService, EmployeeService>();
builder.Services.AddTransient<IEmployeeService, EmployeeService>();
```

Please do let me know how to register this http service with blazor component.

Comment: Have you check the documentation here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/fundamentals/dependency-injection?view=aspnetcore-3.1

Comment: Yes i did check that but not much help

Comment: @vikassaini, I have given you a reply, you can try this code , if you have some other problems, please let me know, if not you can accept it as the answer.

Answer (score 1):

> Please do let me know how to register this http service with blazor
> component.

Just inject `HttpClient` by the following code(**which is writing in ConfigureServices in startup.cs**):

```
   using System.Net.Http;

    services.AddHttpClient();    
    services.AddScoped<HttpClient>();
```

If you want to inject in **program.cs**, you can use the following writing:

```
      using System.Net.Http;    
      
        public class Program
        {
            public static void Main(string[] args)
            {
                CreateHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
            }
    
            public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
                Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
                    .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
                    {
                        webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
                        webBuilder.ConfigureServices(services =>
                        {
                            services.AddHttpClient();
                            services.AddScoped<HttpClient>();
                            services.AddScoped<IEmployeeService, EmployeeService>();
                        });
                    });
        }
```